# How to get the latest date record joining with two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

First table: **status**

```
ID  Status   Date
=======================
1   PRO      2010-02-10
1   LWR      2011-06-08
1   Active   2011-06-10
2   PRO      2010-02-10
2   LWR      2011-06-08
2   PRO      2011-06-10
3   PRO      2010-02-10
3   LWR      2011-06-08
3   APS      2011-06-10
```

Second table: **profile**

```
ID  Name
=========
1   Suba
2   Jhon
3   Felix
```

Expected output:

```
ID  Name    Status   Date
===============================
1   Suba    Active   2011-06-10
2   Jhon    PRO      2011-06-10
3   Felix   APS      2011-06-10
```

How can I get the maximum / latest date value from records?

Comment: From your examples it is not clear whether you need to select *any* rows with maximum dates or just those with `Status = 'active'`.

Comment: I want the status with respective maximum date or Latest date. In other way.. What is the maximum date, then bring up the respective status Group by id

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
  JOIN (SELECT t.id,
               MAX(t.date) AS max_date
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.id) b ON b.id = a.id
                      AND b.max_date = a.date
```

Comment: @Bohemian: It is not clumsy. 'Other answer' (Joel's, I presume) simply shows a different understanding of the not very clear question.

Comment: @Bohemian: "clumsy" isn't constructive criticism, much less worth a downvote.  It's the OP that sets the requirements, and whom they should be clarified with if necessary.

Comment: When I use this query, It does not bring the correspond status filed. It only picked up maximum date. I want the status with respective maximum date

Comment: I want the status with respective maximum date or Latest date. In other way.. What is the maximum date, then bring up the respective status Group by id

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a table there. I only see one, and you don't need to join it to anything to get your desired results.

```
SELECT ID, Status, MAX(date) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE status='active' /* optional */
GROUP BY ID, Status
```

Also, the dates you're showing don't match how sql server normally formats dates.  Are you sure that's a datetime column?  If it's not, it should be. Fix that before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, max(date) as max_date FROM `table` order by max_date desc;
```