# mysql MAX query not returning latest record on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is returning the correct data except the left join is not returning the latest record (ordering by dateuploaded column) Thanks for any help.

```
select a.*,p.thumbnailphotopath as Picture from album_access ac 
inner join albums a on a.ID = ac.AlbumID 
left join (select albumid, thumbnailphotopath,max(DateUploaded) from photos where IsProcessed = 1 and IsPrivate = 0 GROUP BY albumID) p on a.ID = p.AlbumID #photos record not latest
where ac.AccessUserID = ? and ac.Ispending = 0 and ac.FullControl = 1 and a.Private = 1 order by a.DateCreated desc limit ?,?;

List of dates that return desc (its returning 2012-05-01 09:45:43 and thats not the latest)
2012-05-01 09:46:17 
2012-05-01 09:46:06
2012-05-01 09:45:43 --Returning this record 
2012-05-01 09:45:30
2012-05-01 09:39:49
```

Comment: `MAX` is not supposed to return the latest record. It is only supposed to return the maximum value of a **single column** (or expression).

Comment: Do you know how i can change my query to pull the latest photo record

Comment: The generic solution is something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274069/251311

Comment: A better generic solution is with a self join instead of a subquery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9473929/168493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a prequery to get the max date uploaded per album, then can get the correct album entry based on the matching album AND date qualifiers...

```
select 
      a.*,
      pFinal.thumbnailphotopath as Picture 
   from 
      album_access ac 
         inner join albums a
            on ac.AlbumID = a.ID
           AND a.Private = 1
         left join ( select
                           p.albumid,
                           max( p.dateUploaded ) as MaxDate
                        from
                           photos p
                        where
                               p.IsProcessed = 1
                           AND p.IsPrivate = 0
                        group by 
                           p.AlbumID ) pMax
            on ac.AlbumID = pMax.AlbumID 
               left join photos pFinal
                  on pMax.AlbumID = pFinal.AlbumID
                 AND pMax.MaxDate = pFinal.DateUpladed
   where 
          ac.AccessUserID = ? 
      and ac.Ispending = 0 
      and ac.FullControl = 1 
   order by 
      a.DateCreated desc 
   limit ?,?;
```